# InvalidPidMappingException causes kafka stream application to shut down

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have this application written in kafka streams. Every now and then it throws InvalidPidMappingException.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidPidMappingException: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id.
```

And I have this snippet of code which sets the Uncaught Exception Handler for the app

```
streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            (Thread thread, Throwable exp) -> {
              log.error("Unhandled exception in thread with name ", exp);
                SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, () -> 1);
            }
    );
```

I understand that this exception occurs when the coordinator expires the producer's transaction id after it has not received any transaction status updates from it.
I have few questions regarding this exception:

1. I thought that after this exception, the producer would retry to
   sync it's transaction id with the coordinator and resume without causing the kafka stream thread to be killed. Even if I change the above code snippet to not exit the Spring Application on InvalidPidMappingException, it still kills the stream thread. Is there a way to avoid the death of streams thread on **InvalidPidMappingException**? I have seen the desired behaviour when there is **UnknownProducerIdException**. Or am I missing something here?
2. Other than transactional id expiration, can there be any other reason for this exception to occur?
3. Why the **InvalidPidMappingException** is handled differently than
   **UnknownProducerIdException**? The former kills the Stream Tread and the latter recovers just fine.

I am using the following versions of the libraries:

```
spring-kafka-version = '2.5.5.RELEASE'
apache-kafka-clientVersion = '2.5.1'
confluent-version = '5.4.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

A few months late, but the [discussion on this Apacha Kafka Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13292) is helpful.
To summarise, with v2.8.0 and above of the Apache Kafka streams library you can use the new *setUncaughtExceptionHandler*() method in *org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams* to handle any uncaught exceptions and keep the stream running by terminating the current thread and creating a new one for future processing by returning *org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler.StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD*.
e.g.

```
kafkaStreams.setStreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler(e -> {
    return StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler.StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD;
});
```

[Javadocs for KafkaStreams::setUncaughtExceptionHandler method added in 2.8.0](https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler))

Comment: We are using kafka-clients:3.4.1 and spring-kafka:3.0.11 and are using Kafka Producer/Consumer APIs. Got this exception for the producer, kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, message), and had to restart the services. Is there an equivelant for the kafkaStreams.setStreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler that we can use to do a REPLACE_THREAD?

Comment: Apologies @ewolfman. I should probably monitor my inbox here on stackoverflow more often than I usually do. For a producer, the Kafka client library already implements retries to resend your message. You should set the producer retry configuration as required. This thread should help. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390761/how-kafka-retries-works-with-request-timeout

Comment: Thanks @scoobs. But I suspect the problem is different and requires a 'replace thread' type of mechanism (or restart of the producer).